# Equivalent of pandas apply in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I really want to be able to run complex functions over a whole column of a spark dataframe, as i would do in Pandas with the apply function.

For example, in Pandas I have an apply function that takes a messy domain like sub-subdomain.subdomain.facebook.co.nz/somequerystring and just outputs facebook.com.

How would I do that in Spark?

I have looked at UDF's but I am not clear how I would run it on a single column.

Let's say I have a simple function like below where I extract different bits of a date from the column of the pandas DF:

```
def format_date(row):
    year = int(row['Contract_Renewal'][7:])
    month = int(row['Contract_Renewal'][4:6])
    day = int(row['Contract_Renewal'][:3])
    date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    return date-now
```

In Pandas I would call it like:

```
df['days_until'] = df.apply(format_date, axis=1)
```

Can I achieve the same in Pyspark?

Comment: Have a look at koalas : https://databricks.com/blog/2019/04/24/koalas-easy-transition-from-pandas-to-apache-spark.html

Comment: Columns is what Spark UDFs take, but the actual function that implements the UDF takes an element of the column type. Then Spark makes sure to call your function for each row. It is the same as in Pandas, just the UDF doesn't receive the full row. The way it works is you write a Python function that takes a string, does the computation and returns the delta. Then you call `pyspark.sql.functions.udf` to register a UDF, and then `df.select(format_date_udf(df['Contract_Renewal']).alias("days_until"))`.

Comment: Also, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52401542/1374437) on how to create Pandas UDFs for use with Spark. Those are faster than regular Python UDFs.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you may be able to use some combination of `regexp_extract` (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=substring#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract),  `regexp_replace` (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=substring#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace), and `split` (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=substring#pyspark.sql.functions.split) to reformat the date the strings.

It's not as clean as defining your own function and using `apply` like Pandas, but it should be more performant than defining a Pandas/Spark UDF.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of PySpark provides a way to run apply() function by leveraging pandas. You can find the example at [PySpark apply Function to Column](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-apply-function-to-column/)

```
# Imports
import pyspark.pandas as ps
import numpy as np

technologies = ({
    'Fee' :[20000,25000,30000,22000,np.NaN],
    'Discount':[1000,2500,1500,1200,3000]
               })
# Create a DataFrame
psdf = ps.DataFrame(technologies)
print(psdf)

def add(row):
   return row[0]+row[1]
   
addDF = psdf.apply(add,axis=1)
print(addDF)
```